# How to run a php script under Window's Task Scheduler that outputs a CSV file

Tags: php, scheduled-tasks, windows-server-2008

I need to run a php script that queries my DB and outputs the results as a CSV file. I have the script to produce the CSV and it worked perfectly when run on web browser. I just need to figure out how to schedule this task on window's Task Scheduler and output a CSV.
I tried the to schedule task and used the command under 'Action' tab:

```
Program/Script -> "C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\v5.3\php.exe"
Add agruments  -> -f C:\inetpub\wwwroot\myweb\csv.php
```

Any help or ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: you have downvotes that are not very fair to my mind. Your question is clear. Already have asked moderation support for your question.

Comment: Actually it's probably better to be on serverfault

Answer (score 0):

I assume that your script is working fine when you're executing it via a browser call (launching firefox and calling uri  http://localhost:8080/myweb/csv.php)

1. install [curl](https://curl.haxx.se/download.html) and do not forget add it to windows PATH
2. make a service that starts your webserver (apache or nginx or tomcat or other) that contains the php pages
3. make a service that starts your Database automaticaly
4. execute curl to execute a GET http://localhost:8080/myweb/csv.php . Very easy do it like this

   curl http://localhost:8080/myweb/csv.php
5. save this "curl" command in a batch file. Let's call it c:\export\csv.bat
6. configure your scheduler to execute the "c:\export\csv.bat" on schedule.

You're done with it.